# Terminal is showing "error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error" when I run "npm run prod" command

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a vue + laravel application. I need to run the production command using this:

```
npm run prod
```

but I got this error message :

```
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.9.1
```

I search on google and added this to the package.json **scripts** key:

```
"serve": "vue-cli-service --openssl-legacy-provider serve",
"build": "vue-cli-service --openssl-legacy-provider build",
"lint": "vue-cli-service --openssl-legacy-provider lint"
```

but stil no solutions. Can you tell me how can I fix it ?

my full package.json file now: https://codeshare.io/3AXbBg

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when i updated nodeJs.

I was able to solve it with a similar solution as you stated in the question.

In my case i have a Laravel/VueJs project so i need to run `npm run hot` to serve the project in development.

I added `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` to the `hot` and `prod` scripts in package.json.

And everything worked fine.
Leaving this here in case the anyone needs it.